# Meaning of notation $f = {1 \over k} 1_{[{1 \over 2k+1},{1 \over 2k} ) }$

Tags: analysis, notation

I found this notation used in an analysis answer on this site, what does multiplying by 1 with this interval in brackets next to it mean?

$$f = \sum_{k=1}^\infty {1 \over k} 1_{[{1 \over 2k+1},{1 \over 2k} ) }$$

Thank you.

Comment: That is the function that is 1 on the indicated set and 0 elsewhere, I believe.

Comment: [Indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Definition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1_{[a,b]}(x)=\begin{cases} 1, x\in [a,b]\\ 0, x\notin [a,b]\end{cases}$

It is the well known indicator function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function#Definition

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a set and $Y\subseteq X,$ then $1_{Y}$ is usually the characteristic or indicator function of $Y,$ i.e., the function $X\to\{0,1\}$ given by
$$1_{Y}(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x\in Y,\\
0 & \text{if }x\not\in Y.
\end{cases}$$